# Is there anyway to recognize just one word without using speech to text api in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, audio-processing, frequency-analysis

I need to turn on something when the user says a given word, Let's say the word is "Hello", So whenever the user says "Hello" I need to turn on something, I only need to recognize this word, And I don't want to use a whole speech to text API to identify just one word. I have tried a few things using frequencies and didn't work. Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It is as hard to recognize one word as it is to recognize several. It may be easier to teach a dog to recognize one command rather than several. That doesn't apply to computer programs.

Comment: You could try drawing a waveform of a well spoken "hello" (as guide) and then compare waveform of user saying a word. If the user's waveform is close in shape (pixels) to the shape of your expected (guide) hello, then you have a match (_ie:_ user said "hello")

Comment: Test everything in a sound editor. Record yourself or others saying "hello" then see the similar shape/pattern of each waveform... **(1)** To draw waveform you decode the audio into PCM (raw audio), decoding gives back an Array of values which can read to draw a waveform (each array value is the amplitude of a sample, there are 44100 samples per sec if audio is 44.1k samplerate). **(2)** To compare two pictures, use an equality check `if A== B` to check similarity of each pixel via a For-loop...

Comment: If you want Frequency Analysis then use FFT algorithm on the audio. If the FFT values of the  user's speech matches (or has high percentage of similarity) to the FFT of your test "hello" then you have a match.

Comment: @VC.One Thank you for the idea, however, I have done the same process you mentioned, I first analyzed the average waveform using audacity and tried this method, The issue is the algorithm needed to be trained using a large amount of data, in my case, it is not possible, This wake-word system is working but not reliable

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is **wake word detection** or **keyword spotting**. In wake word detection, the goal is to trigger the output when a specified word is heard in input.

There are several good libraries to do this. For example check these ones:

https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine (it requires access key from their website)

https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-precise (It looks like its free)

Comment: Thank you, However, this is not the exact answer I was looking for, It's hard to use something like this in my application due to the long response time when detecting a word. I'm trying to detect it under 100ms